# Image wrapping inside parcolumns

Tags: graphics, wrap, parcolumns

I can't get image wrapping inside `parcolumns`. I have been trying for a long time, and here is what I've got so far:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % оролтын кодчилол UTF-8
\usepackage[mongolian]{babel} % lh фонт бүхий T2A кодчилол

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Бодлого 1}
$SABS$ тетраэдр өгөгдөв. Тус тедраедрыг $\alpha$ хавтгайгаар огтлох оглолыг байгуул. Үүнд $\alpha\textsubscript{огт} \ni M;N;P | M \in AB; N \equiv S; P \equiv C |$ болно.


\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,sloppy,rulebetween,colwidths={1=.30\linewidth,2=.65\linewidth}]{2}
\colchunk[1]{
\underline{Өгсөн нь:} $SABC$ тетраэдр, $\alpha\textsubscript{огт} \ni M; N; P$, $M \in AB$, $N \equiv S$, $ P \equiv C$\\
\underline{Батлах нь:} $ \phi\textsubscript{огт}=(MNP)$\\

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{b1-1} 
\caption{Caption1}
\label{fig:}
\end{wrapfigure}


} 


\colchunk[2]{
\textit{\underline{Байгуулсан нь:}}
\\1) Өгөгдсөн нөхцөл ёсоор $ S \equiv N$; $C \equiv P$ гэж өгөгдсөн тул $NP$-г шууд огтлогч шулуун гэдгийг харж болно. Иймд $[NP]$-г татлаа
\\2) Одоо $ N; M \in \triangle ABS $ тул $\triangle ABS$-г авч үзье. Үүнд
$
\left.\
\begin{array}{rl}
M; N \in \alpha\textsubscript{огт}\\
N \in \triangle ABS \\
M \in AB \subset \triangle ABS
\end{array} \right\rbrace
\Rightarrow C_{2}
$ аксиом ёсоор $[MN] = \alpha\textsubscript{огт} \cap \triangle ABS$ болно.
\\3) Одоо $M; P \in \alpha\textsubscript{огт}$ тул түүний оршин байгаа $\triangle ABC$-г авч үзье.
$
\left.\
\begin{array}{rl}
M; З \in \alpha\textsubscript{огт}\\
N \in AB \subset \triangle ABC \\
C \equiv P
\end{array} \right\rbrace
\Rightarrow C_{2}
$ аксиомоор 
$ [MP] = \alpha\textsubscript{огт} \cap  \triangle ABC $ болно.
\\Ингээд $ \phi\textsubscript{огт} = \triangle MNP $ байгуулагдлаа.
}
\end{parcolumns}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{b1-2}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{b1-3}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You better use `paracol` instead of `parcolumns`. It's able to handle floats so (if there ever was,) there's no longer any need for `wrapfigure`.

Also I used `\begin{enumerate} ... \end{enumerate}` for your enumeration.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % оролтын кодчилол UTF-8
\usepackage[mongolian]{babel} % lh фонт бүхий T2A кодчилол
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}
    \paragraph{Бодлого 1}
        $SABS$ тетраэдр өгөгдөв. Тус тедраедрыг $\alpha$ хавтгайгаар огтлох оглолыг байгуул. Үүнд $\alpha\textsubscript{огт} \ni M;N;P | M \in AB; N \equiv S; P \equiv C |$ болно.

    \columnratio{0.3,0.7}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
        \setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
        \begin{leftcolumn}
            \noindent \underline{Өгсөн нь:} \\ $SABC$ тетраэдр, \\ 
            $\alpha\textsubscript{огт} \ni M; N; P, M \in AB$, \\
            $N \equiv S, P \equiv C$ \\
            \underline{Батлах нь:} \\
            $\phi\textsubscript{огт}=(MNP)$ \\
            \begin{figure}[h]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{b1-1} 
                \caption{Caption1}
                \label{fig:}
            \end{figure}
        \end{leftcolumn}

        \begin{rightcolumn}
            \noindent\textit{\underline{Байгуулсан нь:}}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Өгөгдсөн нөхцөл ёсоор $S \equiv N; C \equiv P$ гэж өгөгдсөн тул $NP$-г шууд огтлогч шулуун гэдгийг харж болно. Иймд $[NP]$-г татлаа
                \item Одоо $N; M \in \triangle ABS$ тул $\triangle ABS$-г авч үзье. Үүнд \\ $\left.\
                \begin{array}{r}
                    M; N \in \alpha\textsubscript{огт} \\
                    N \in \triangle ABS \\
                    M \in AB \subset \triangle ABS
                \end{array}
                \right\rbrace\Rightarrow C_{2}$ аксиом ёсоор $[MN] = \alpha\textsubscript{огт} \cap \triangle ABS$ болно.
                \item Одоо $M; P \in \alpha\textsubscript{огт}$ тул түүний оршин байгаа $\triangle ABC$-г авч үзье. \\ $\left.\
                \begin{array}{r}
                    M; З \in \alpha\textsubscript{огт} \\
                    N \in AB \subset \triangle ABC \\
                    C \equiv P
                \end{array}
                \right\rbrace\Rightarrow C_{2}$ аксиомоор $[MP] = \alpha\textsubscript{огт} \cap  \triangle ABC $ болно. \\
                Ингээд $ \phi\textsubscript{огт} = \triangle MNP $ байгуулагдлаа.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{rightcolumn}
    \end{paracol}

    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{b1-2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{b1-3}

\end{document}
```

[image]